# Facebook login button won't do anything when clicked on?

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom-events

On this page: http://friendsconnect.org/shadowlink/ you can see in the lower right hand corner  I have a Facebook login button titled "Connect with Facebook". However the button won't do anything when clicked. What am I doing wrong?

Button code:

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream">Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Page will not work in Chrome, Safari, or Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are missing this code which can be placed anywhere in your page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

If you look at the Chrome debugger tools console you will see it telling you that this is missing because you have a `document.getElementById('fb-root')` call that is returning null.

Comment: Thanks for you're help. I have added the DIV element but it still isn't working. I added it to the bottom of the page, is the placement wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Were you maybe already logged in to Facebook?  If you are already logged in and have already authorized the app, the button may appear to do nothing if you are only catching auth.login and auth.logout events since neither of those is actually happening.

Comment: Have no ides why this was down-voted...I was pointing out a common situation that can make the button appear to do nothing just like the OP described.  And it's easy enough to test--add some extra permission to the button that wasn't asked for before, and see if it works then.